# Как подключиться к базе данных PostgreSQL?

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, postgresql

Проблема такая, решил создать простое приложение по отборке юзеров.

[image: Сама форма, через которую вводятся пользователи, а позднее удаляются и соратируются]

Но у меня никак не получается подключиться к самой БД.
Вот код, который я оспользовал:

```
String connectionString = "Server=localhost;Port=5432;User=postgres;Password=postgres;Database=postgres;";
NpgsqlConnection npgSqlConnection = new NpgsqlConnection(connectionString);
npgSqlConnection.Open();
```

При запуске отладки, выподит ошибку:
[image: Ошибка :с]

Подскажите пожалуйста, куда вставить код, и каким он был, был бы рад указанию самой ошибки, чтобы в дальнейшем не совершать такой же.

Скрин с pgAdmin 4:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пароль: postgres

Comment: Ваша строка соединения похожа на ту, которая используется для SqlServer. См. https://www.connectionstrings.com/postgresql/ и https://www.npgsql.org/doc/connection-string-parameters.html - вместо User должно быть User Id или Username (как я понимаю, зависит от используемого провайдера).

Comment: спасибо, сейчас попробую

Comment: Можете использовать что-то вроде этого:  Server=postgres;userid=postgres;Password=123456;Database=bd;Port=5432

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В App.config добавить

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="ИмяПодключения"
         connectionString="Server=Сервер;Port=5432;Database=База;User Id=postgres;Password=пароль"
         providerName="Npgsql"/>
  </connectionStrings>
```

в коде использовать

```
var connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ИмяПодключения"].ConnectionString;
```